# What is the exact difference between r+ and w+ modes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, mode

I tried to use both of them opening a file but got the same result.

`w+` is supposed to create a new file if it doesn't exist while `r+` not. 
**Is this the only difference?**

For example, this is an **initial file `file.txt`**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

1) **`file.txt`** after implementing of **`r+` mode** (writing the word "hello")

```
hello
```

2) **`file.txt`** after implementing of **`w+`** **mode**

```
hello
```

I guessed that `r+` would append an input to the beginning of the file.

EDITED:
So, the 1st difference is about creating a file that doesn't exist and the 2nd difference is that r+ overwrites while w+ truncates, right? (than the question arises whether overwriting and truncating are the same concepts or not)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `file.txt` first and you'll understand the difference.

`w+` will create the file.